# taking screenshots works fine in iOS5,but not in iOS4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Xcode4.2，SDK is 5.0

QuartzCore.framework has been added.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

-(UIImage*)getShot
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize); 
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return viewImage;
}
```

it works fine in iOS5，but not in iOS4.

Whether I use the

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0)
```

or

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)
```

it doesn't help.

Comment: I just figure it out that its the Xcode4.2's problem.If I use Xcode4.1, which only support iOS4,it works fine in iOS4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*) takeScreenshot
{
        if (iosVersionIsAtLeast(4.0))
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
        else
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        // save to UIImage
        UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenshot;
}
```

Comment: if I want to use iosVersionIsAtLeast() method,what do I need to import?

Comment: Whether I use the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() or UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(),it doesn't help.